# Getting uncaught exception of type NSException with CLLocationCoordinate2D initialization

Tags: swift, xcode, core-location

I am trying to find the distance between two cities using CoreLocation, but for some reason I'm getting an error after initializing two CLLocationCoordinate2D variables. I have to initialize them beforehand because they're in a closure.

Here's my code:

```
let geoC = CLGeocoder()

func distance(_ cityA: String, _ cityB: String) -> Double{
    var coordinatesA = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0)
    var coordinatesB = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(0.0, 0.0)
    print("check")
    geoC.geocodeAddressString(cityA, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, errorA) -> Void in
        if (errorA) != nil{
            print("Error", errorA!)
        }
        if let placemarkA = placemarks?.first{
            coordinatesA = placemarkA.location!.coordinate
        }
    })

    geoC.geocodeAddressString(cityA, completionHandler: {
        (placemarks, errorB) -> Void in
        if (errorB) != nil{
            print("Error", errorB!)
        }
        if let placemarkB = placemarks?.first{
            coordinatesB = placemarkB.location!.coordinate
        }
    })
    let coordinateA = CLLocation(latitude: coordinatesA.latitude, longitude: coordinatesA.longitude)
    let coordinateB = CLLocation(latitude: coordinatesB.latitude, longitude: coordinatesB.longitude)

    return coordinateA.distance(from:coordinateB)

}
```

The error I get is: *libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.*

I am using XCode Playground.

Comment: geocodeAddressString is asynchronous. Your code does not take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Actually Playground is preventing you to see error details. Such crashes will be caused when something is impossible for Swift Playground to execute, in such cases, Playground would not be able to show what caused the `uncaught terminating exception` or a type of `SIGABRT`.
For example, if I position a button at as:

```
var button = CGRect(x: 200, y:200, width:30, height: 30)
```

and the view in which I add it is only `50x50` then it would definitely cause an error.

Comment: Tried running it from the command line and while it was successfully compiled, it seems like placemarks couldn't be unwrapped (aka it wasn't retrieving any data, I think). My input was "Atlanta" and "Chicago". I also tried using more specific addresses, but the same thing happened.